# Predicted value stay constant XGBRegressor

Tags: python, dataframe, scikit-learn, regression, xgboost

For illustration purpose, I want to forecast exchange rate. From the csv file enclosed and I created 2 columns for prior 1 month and prior 2 month. After performing train_test_split, I use XGBRegressor to forecast price.

Surprisingly, the predicted value turns out almost constant.

Excel data file link (pls click on the download icon): https://easyupload.io/1kf2hg

My code are enclosed.

```
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'rate.csv')
df['prior_1_month'] = df['price'].shift(1)
df['prior_2_month'] = df['price'].shift(2)
df=df.dropna()

x = df[['prior_1_month','prior_2_month']]
y = df["price"]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, shuffle=False)

# print(X_train[:3]);print(X_test[:3]);print(y_train[:3]);print(y_test[:3])

reg = xgb.XGBRegressor(n_estimators=1000)
reg.fit(X_train[[ 'prior_1_month', 'prior_2_month']], y_train, verbose = True)
# xgb.plot_importance(reg)

X_test['predicted_value_ML_1'] = reg.predict(X_test)
print(X_test)
y_test
```

Comment: Did you apply any scaling?

Comment: No I don't. Just straight like that.

Comment: I think you should, if you need I can prepare the code to do it

Comment: I don't know how to do scaling. can you please help

Comment: @jeste_artyste has already answered, try the code and let us know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use booster='gblinear' parameter.

```
reg = xgb.XGBRegressor(booster='gblinear')
```

The predicted value stay constant because input data is sample and using tree-based regression to predict. Using a linear routine could solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your input data is in general quite constant. Try to use some sort of scaling eg. Change "price" column like:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import numpy as np

scaler = MinMaxScaler()

reshaped_data = np.reshape(df['price'], (-1, 1))
model = scaler.fit(reshaped_data)
scaled_data = model.transform(reshaped_data)
```

Now after having scaled data you can place it as a "price" column